# Как правильно организовать взаимодействия инпутов и радио/чекбоксов в форме?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть форма внутри которой расположены пары - обычный инпут и динамически, либо радио, либо чекбокс, справа от инпута. Пары также создаются и динамически отрисовываются самим пользователем, т.е. изначально неизвестно их количество. Данные нужно отправлять на сервер. Поле name у всех видов инпутов задаётся в виде массива, т.е. для текстовых как:
`name="name[]"`
А для радио/чекбоксов условный
`name="correct[]"`

Обрабатываю запрос на стороне сервера, приходит в реквесте массив name - всё ок. Однако с радиокнопками приходит массив из одного значения - "on". И что мне с ним спрашивается делать? Как привязать к нужному элементу name в массиве? Приходили бы все значения и on и off я бы сравнивал по индексу.

Update:
Пары на странице:

```
<div class="answers" id="answers">
   <div class="mb-4 row">
      <div class="group col"><label for="name" class="form-label">Название ответа</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name[]"></div>
      <input class="col input inp-type" name="correct[]" value="off" type="radio">
   </div>
   <div class="mb-4 row">
      <div class="group col"><label for="name" class="form-label">Название ответа</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name[]"></div>
      <input class="col input inp-type" name="correct[]" value="off" type="radio">
   </div>
   <div class="mb-4 row">
      <div class="group col"><label for="name" class="form-label">Название ответа</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name[]"></div>
      <input class="col input inp-type" name="correct[]" value="off" type="radio">
   </div>
</div>
```

Запрос:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите, как у вас выглядят радиокнопки в форме и что приходит на сервер

Comment: @SwaD обновил пост

Comment: radio группируются по имени, и возвращается value выбранного. вам надо у них сделать разное value. Ну и в целом `name="correct[]"` выглядит не красиво, т.к. []  это массив или обращение по индексу.

Comment: Так я же написал, что разные value сделать не могу, т.к. пары создаются динамически. Изначально вообще ничего нет - тыкнул на кнопку добавилась пара, и тыкать можно сколько угодно. Так какие альтернативы массиву есть?

Comment: Создайте переменную. Тык - значение один, Еще тык, значение два. radio будет группироваться. Не знаю, с какой целью делаются тыки и почему на все тыки один радио. Может стоит подумать на счет чекбоксов?

Comment: @SwaD Идея с переменной офигенная и работает, спасибо! А по поводу типа кнопок - так они тоже задаются динамически, в зависимости от выбора пользователя, они либо radio, либо checkbox :)

Comment: Ну далее как говорится ХЗ. Не понимая, какую задачу вы решаете, как работает логика вашего приложения, для каких целей радио или чекбоксы, то дать какой то объективный совет сложно. Просто помните, radio будет группироваться по имени, чекбоксы нет. Если радио с одним именем один, его нельзя отжать, как чекбокс. Возможно, для радио, стоит добавлять сразу 2 для тыка. Эти 2 с одним имененем и у каждого значения on или off. А для другого тыка такую же комбинацию но с другим именем радио(из переменной, созданной для тыка)

Answer (score 0):

Можно самому сформировать нужные данные для сервера...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => {
    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        let data = [...this.querySelectorAll('.mb-4')].reduce((a, o) => {
            const name = o.querySelector('[name="name[]"]').value
            const correct = o.querySelector('[name="correct[]"]').checked
            return [...a, {name, correct}]
        }, [])
        // это уже можно отправлять
        console.log(data)
        // или это
        data = JSON.stringify(data)
        console.log(data)
    })
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <button>Test</button>
    <div class="answers" id="answers">
        <div class="mb-4 row">
            <div class="group col">
                <label for="name" class="form-label">Название ответа</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name[]">
            </div>
            <input class="col input inp-type" name="correct[]" value="off" type="radio">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4 row">
            <div class="group col">
                <label for="name" class="form-label">Название ответа</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name[]">
            </div>
            <input class="col input inp-type" name="correct[]" value="off" type="radio">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4 row">
            <div class="group col">
                <label for="name" class="form-label">Название ответа</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name[]">
            </div>
            <input class="col input inp-type" name="correct[]" value="off" type="radio">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```